# Custom fields not coming during user creation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-3.0

I have created a custom user creation form:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Here is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Our own User model. Made by overriding Django's own AbstractUser model.
    We need to define this as the main user model in settings.py with 
    variable AUTH_USER_MODEL *IMPORTANT* 
    """
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name="email address"
    )

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is the admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)})
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Note the first_name and last_name. These two fields aren't coming in the form. What am I doing wrong due to which these fields aren't coming in the user creation form? I've followed all the steps from the documentation.

Comment: You may need to override `UserAdmin.add_fieldsets` if I'm reading the docs correctly

Comment: in your project settings you have to mention your auth user model

Comment: @lain Let me see.

Comment: @bmons already done. I'm getting the form. My question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You need to add add_fieldsets in order to achieve this.

```
add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
```